# What is the safest way to reset a graph?

Tags: core-plot

Scenario:
   I use the same graph space (plotspace) to plot 3-month, 6-month, ... 3-year data.  I switch from one to the other via a tab-like control.

However, I'm getting 'bleed' from other graphs when I switch graphs.
If I were to [graph release] & re-create the graph, I eventually get crash due to accessing a released object.

That is:

```
if (graph is not nil) {
  release it;
}
create it
```

So, is there a safe way to reset the plotspace, theme & range between plot-set displays; and hence avoid the bleeding (e.g., labels tripping over each other, etc.).

Ric.

Answer (score 0):

Just update the axis labels, plot ranges, and other appearance-related properties within the same method so that everything gets updated before Core Animation gives the graph a chance to update its layout and redraw everything.

It sounds like you're keeping a weak reference to the old graph (or one of its parts like a plot) somewhere after releasing it. Double-check your memory management.